# How to pass --pager option to mysql command line

Tags: mysql

I'm on Windows 7 and I have created a command line shortcut for MySQL. However, when I try to pass `--pager "less -SFX"` option to `mysql.exe`, I get a following error :

```
L:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql.exe: unknown option '--pager'
```

My Shortcut :

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\mintty.exe" -e 
"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\winpty.exe"
"L:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -u root -h 127.0.0.1 --pager "less -SFX"
```

Does anyone know how to pass --pager option while invoking mysql.exe?

P.S. I do not want to set a default pager under `my.cnf`. Instead, I would like to pass it as a parameter to `mysql.exe`.

Comment: `pager [command], \P [command] ... Output paging works only in Unix because it uses the popen() function, which does not exist on Windows. For Windows, the tee option can be used instead to save query output, although it is not as convenient as pager for browsing output in some situations.`, see [4.5.1.2 mysql Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html).

Comment: Please feel free to put your comment as an answer. I would mark it as a correct answer to this question. Thank You