# How do I use mysql's --pager option on Linux command

Tags: mysql-5.5

Hi I am using MySQL server 5.5.58 installed on RHEL7.

I am trying to keep track of **Pages Made Young** from ***show engine innodb status***.
I want to filter this information from the innodb monitor output.
Following is the command I use from  the Linux command line, but it fails to give desired output. I am trying to put this command in a shell script so that I will have a track of changes.

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysqldump.cnf --pager="egrep -i pages made young" -e "show engine innodb status;"
```

**It gives me all the output, it does not filter.**

I tried adding the line (pager="egrep -i pages made young") to the additional config file 
--defaults-extra-file **/etc/mysqldump.cnf** and to the config file **/etc/my.cnf** too, but the information is not filtered.

[How do you set a default pager for the MySQL client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611974/how-do-you-set-a-default-pager-for-the-mysql-client)  and [How to pass --pager option to mysql command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604133/how-to-pass-pager-option-to-mysql-command-line) --> were not helpful.

The mysql man page says that **Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename], and so forth. This option works only on Unix and only in interactive mode.** It doesn't include the grep or egrep filters in the list.

Does it mean that I can't use it on Linux command line?

When I use the same from the mysql shell, there's no problem.

```
[bunny@localhost]> pager egrep -i 'pages made young'; show engine innodb status;
PAGER set to 'egrep -i 'pages made young''
Pages made young 323890330, not young 0
Pages made young 40605338, not young 0
Pages made young 40353291, not young 0
Pages made young 40467266, not young 0
Pages made young 40284375, not young 0
Pages made young 40783248, not young 0
Pages made young 40164275, not young 0
Pages made young 40682690, not young 0
Pages made young 40549847, not young 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `select pages_made_young from INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS;` I can use this, but I am curious if I can use --pager from linux command line/

Comment: Moreover, when I had put pager="less -SFX" or pager="egrep -i pages made young" in the my.cnf file under [client] section, I was not able to run the mysqltuner script.